# User info sidebar not refreshed if wireless or mobile data is enabled after starting app

Tags: bug, android-app

The user info in the side bar is not displayed if I enable wireless or mobile data after starting the app.

1. Disable wireless and mobile data connectivity.
2. Start the Stack Exchange app.
3. Pull to refresh - "Failed to load data" message is displayed.
4. Check the side bar. No user info or user specific sites are displayed.
5. Enable wireless or mobile data connectivity.
6. Once connection is available, pull to refresh. The posts will be refreshed.
7. check the side bar. No user info or user specific sites are displayed.

[image]

The app has to be restarted to get the user info.

Stack Exchange Android App Version 1.0.9